# Application Express (Apex) - Displaying the result from cascading list of values (LOV)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, lov

I have been working on this for a while now and am stuck on finding the solution.

This is what I would like the end result to be - displaying this table below based on the selection from LOV #1 AND LOV #2:

[image]

But this is what I am getting:

[image]

How do I make the page to display the result of the 2nd LOV selection into the likeness of the first picture?

I am on Apex version: 4.2.0.00.27

Comment: I'm confused - your first picture is of a report region, the second of a select list item.  They are two different things.

Comment: Create a classic report with the query from the select list on the second image